# Convert strings of data to "Data" objects in R

Tags: r, date, csv

My problem is that the `as.Date` function does not convert the values in a `date` column of a data frame into `Date objects`.

I have a `data.frame` `nmmaps`. Here is a portion of it.

```
city     date death temp dewpoint     pm10       o3 time season

1 chic 1/1/1987   130 31.5   31.500 27.79119 4.025928    1 winter

2 chic 1/2/1987   150 33.0   29.875       NA 4.579652    2 winter

3 chic 1/3/1987   101 33.0   27.375 33.67382 3.400928    3 winter

4 chic 1/4/1987   135 29.0   28.625 40.79119 3.942595    4 winter

5 chic 1/5/1987   126 32.0   28.875       NA 4.400928    5 winter

6 chic 1/6/1987   130 40.0   35.125 41.79119 5.984261    6 winter
```

I imported the data from an Excel file with the following command:

```
nmmaps <- read.csv("chicago-nmmaps.csv" , as.is = T)
```

When I get to the point of converting by as.Date, I enter 
`nmmaps$date <- as.Date(nmmaps$date)` and get a `data.frame` shown below.

```
  city       date death temp dewpoint     pm10       o3 time season

1 chic 0001-01-19   130 31.5   31.500 27.79119 4.025928    1 winter

2 chic 0001-02-19   150 33.0   29.875       NA 4.579652    2 winter

3 chic 0001-03-19   101 33.0   27.375 33.67382 3.400928    3 winter

4 chic 0001-04-19   135 29.0   28.625 40.79119 3.942595    4 winter

5 chic 0001-05-19   126 32.0   28.875       NA 4.400928    5 winter

6 chic 0001-06-19   130 40.0   35.125 41.79119 5.984261    6 winter
```

Why are the dates shown this way? Also, some dates have a `NA` field. I would like the years to shown as 1987, 1988, 1989, etc..

Comment: Downvote for (apparently) failing to read the documentation for `as.Date` or do any searching on SO.

Comment: You should supply the `format` argument of `as.Date` function in order to "tell" how to parse the dates.

Comment: @BondedDust I did look at the documentation via. ?as.Date(). I just missed the fact that there was a default format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you read on the R help page for as.Date by typing ?as.Date you will see there is a default format assumed if you do not specify. So to specify for your data you would do

```
      nmmaps$date <- as.Date(nmmaps$date, format="%m/%d/%Y")
```

Comment: I tried that but, now all the values in the data column are being converted to NA.

Comment: @Crt works fine for me. Can you post exactly what you tried?

Comment: @NickK I figured it out, thanks